# My array of objects is not working correctly with my ng-select?

Tags: angularjs

I have this array of objects:

```
var abc = [
   {"id":28,"name":"Actions, State & Occurences"},     
   {"id":29,"name":"Descriptive Words & Modifiers"}  
   {"id":30,"name":"Counting & Measurement"},
   {"id":31,"name":"Time & Dates"}]
```

Here's the select I am using:

```
   {{ row.categoryId }}
   <select class="select"
           convert-to-number
           ng-options="option.name for option in abc track by option.id"
           ng-model="row.categoryId"></select>
```

The problem I have is that the row.categoryId is a number and the correct value is not being selected. When I do select a value here's what my row.categoryId gets set to:

```
  {"id":28,"name":"Actions, State & Occurences"}
```

Can someone tell me is there a way I can make this work correctly so that it sets and uses the id value instead of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alan, you can use the as clause in the `ng-options` directive in order to tell AngularJS what you want to be set into the variable used in the `ng-model` directive.

Check the below example(the selected option doesn't appear maybe problem with the version it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ndLtx4ew/)), here from the `option` object in the `ctrl.abc` array the `id` property is set (selected) into the `ctrl.row.categoryId` and the `name` property is displayed to the user.

You can find more information about ng-options [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```js
angular
   .module('demo', [])
   .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.abc = [
    { "id":28,"name":"Actions, State & Occurences" },
    { "id":29,"name":"Descriptive Words & Modifiers" },
    { "id":30,"name":"Counting & Measurement" },
    { "id":31,"name":"Time & Dates" }];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    {{ ctrl.row.categoryId }}
    <select class="select"
           convert-to-number
           ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in ctrl.abc track by option.id"
           ng-model="ctrl.row.categoryId">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need to use track by if you will be setting the selected option in the select element using the exact same property value which you get from the `ng-options` directive when a user selects an option.

Check the below sample which sets a selected option using an id of the item. If you would want to set the selected option using a different property than the id property then you can use the track by clause in the `ng-options` directive.

```js
 angular
   .module('demo', [])
   .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.abc = [
    {"id":28,"name":"Actions, State & Occurences"},
    {"id":29,"name":"Descriptive Words & Modifiers"},
    {"id":30,"name":"Counting & Measurement"},
    {"id":31,"name":"Time & Dates"}];
  
  setItem();
  
  function setItem() {
    vm.row = {
      categoryId: 30
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.row.categoryId}}
    <select class="select"
           convert-to-number
           ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in ctrl.abc"
           ng-model="ctrl.row.categoryId">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-options="option.id as option.name for option  in abc track by option.id"
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cdwY1EzKRAL0qlwC9eyO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use $scope.abc instead of var abc. and replace your select tag with this

```
 <select class="select"  ng-options="option  as option.name for option in abc track by option.id"
       ng-model="row.categoryId"></select>
```

And if you need the first value to be pre-selected inside the select tag kindly assign the ng-model to first value of the array like this 
$scope.row.categoryId = $scope.abc[0];
That should fix your problem